# Actualización cíclica de fragmento

Tags: java, android

En la app que estoy probando quiero tener un fragment que se repite en otros fragments y que debe actualizar un valor ciclicamente (por ejemplo cada segundo).

En los códigos que adjunto, el valor a mostrar en el fragment, cambia (según el depurador), pero no actualiza el valor en pantalla.

El código que adjunto es el ejemplo de Navigation drawer views activity que tiene Android Studio añadiendo un fragmento que quiero que se repita en 2 de los 3 fragments que crea por defecto.

Adjunto el homefragment que es en uno de los que quiero que se vea y el fragment que he creado.

Saludos y gracias por vuestro tiempo.
Este es el homefragment

```
package com.example.prueba.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.prueba.R;
import com.example.prueba.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;
import com.example.prueba.ui.frag_1.UnoFragment;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
    public Integer contador;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        final TextView textView = binding.textHome;
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);
        contador=0;
        //datos para transferir al fragment
        Bundle datosAEnviar = new Bundle();
        //((UnoFragment) fragment).actualizarValores();
        //Crear bundle, que son los datos que pasaremos

        // Preparar el fragmento
        Fragment fragmento = new UnoFragment();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerViewUnoHome, fragmento);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerViewUnoHome);
                if (fragmento != null) {
                    contador += 1;
                    // Aquí pon todos los datos que quieras en formato clave, valor
                    datosAEnviar.putInt("contador", contador);                    // ¡Importante! darle argumentos
                    fragmento.setArguments(datosAEnviar);
                    // Terminar transición y nos vemos en el fragmento de destino
                    ((UnoFragment) fragmento).actualizarContenido(contador);

                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1000 es el tiempo en milisegundos entre cada actualización
            }
        }, 1000);



        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Este el unofragment

```
package com.example.prueba.ui.frag_1;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.prueba.R;


public class UnoFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView tv_valor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uno, container, false);
        tv_valor = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tv_valor);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Bundle datosRecuperados = getArguments();
        if (datosRecuperados == null) {
            // No hay datos, manejar excepción
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uno, container, false);

        }
        // Y ahora puedes recuperar usando get en lugar de put
        Integer contador = datosRecuperados.getInt("contador",0);
        tv_valor.setText(String.valueOf(contador));


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uno, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    }

    //aunque llega el valor cambiado, no cambia en la pantalla
    public void actualizarContenido(Integer contador) {
        // Actualiza el contenido aquí
        boolean b = (tv_valor == null);
        if (!b) {
            tv_valor.setText(String.valueOf(contador));
        }

    }
}
```

Este el home layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerViewUnoHome"
        android:layout_width="341dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_uno"
        android:name="com.example.prueba.ui.frag_1.UnoFragment"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_home"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="28dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Y este el Uno fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fr_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F44336"
    tools:context=".ui.frag_1.UnoFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_valor"
            android:textSize="34sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_valor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="34sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```